# Is there an GTalk application for the iPad 2?

Tags: video, ipad, google-apps

Is there an application that will allow me to do video talk using Google Talk from my iPad 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Vtok](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/vtok-google-video-chat/id421102042).